# page: copyToSection failing with error code 19999 with both OneNote and Microsoft graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

This occurs now consistently on the two tenants I have access to.

```
POST .../v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{id}/copyToSection
{
  "id": "id-value",
  "groupId": "groupId-value"
}
```

With the initial response of 202, "status":"not started"

X-CorrelationId: 0b2f5dec-34d8-4462-94e5-7fbf1474f4dc

And on polling with

```
GET .../v1.0/me/onenote/operations/{id}
```

Receiving a 200 response but with

"Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request."

X-CorrelationId: 9f923783-aaa1-4574-945e-7a76cd578ee2

My workaround is to get all the extracted information from the page to be copied with

```
GET .../v1.0/me/notes/pages/{id}/?includeinkML=true&preAuthenticated=true&includeIDs=true
```

and rebuild/create the page copy, but this doesn't allow me to set a picture as a background and muddles up the images and text box layering.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue. Working towards a fix soon. Will reply back here when done. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks Manjusha, where does the status of known issues get published?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed a couple of weeks back. Sorry for the delayed response

Comment: This issue has recurred. The error now is 20280. "Transient error occured while processing request. {0}".